# Java,string,sql ....... id combination of integer and string

Tags: java, database, string, swing

I m making a application in netbeans  (java) . this application has unique id combination of string and integer like abc/111 or xyz/253 and the integer part should increase by when new entry takes place in the database i.e. abc/112 and xyz/254.  problem is

the value of integer part increase till 10 in proper way but after that it does not increse and remain same for further entries in database.

I used following code-

```
try{
    String sql = "SELECT RegNumber FROM Death ORDER BY RegNumber DESC   ";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            String add1 = rs.getString("RegNumber");
            String[] parts= add1.split("/");
            String part1= parts[0];
            String part2= parts[1];
            int a,b;
            a= Integer.parseInt(part2);
            b=a+1;

            jTextField20.setText(""+part1+"/"+b);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done");
        }
    }
```

"Integer part increase till 10" means that if I start the first value of id in database like "abc/1" then new id generates automatically for the next entry with the increasing value 1 that is "abc/2" and for next entry it is "abc/3" and so on.......
like

abc/4,
 abc/5,
 abc/6,
 abc/7,
 abc/8,
 abc/9,
 abc/10

but when it is "abc/10" the new generated id remains same i.e. "abc/10" for every new entry in database. (I am using MS Access 2007 and the id is of text type) (The first id in database creates by the application not by the database itself )

Comment: you need to provide the format of the values of RegNumber and a few samples.

Comment: Check the values in the database ..

Comment: Describe the problem more clearly!

Comment: Are the id's created by your application or by your database? The code above seems to only be for retrieving them

Comment: "he value of integer part increase till 10 in proper way". Does that mean for 10 entries in database. If so make sure whatever are getting from DB is actually changing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very clearly, what is "integer part increase till 10"? if your mean integer length is 10, you should check column type length in your table.